# Loading external data from inside PDF (iText and Adobe Javascript)

Tags: javascript, pdf, itext

Is it possible to load external data from inside PDF file?

my constraints:

1. PDF Form is filled only using Acrobat Reader and offline filling (user's computer)
2. PDF Form is generated on server side, with Adobe javascript injected by itext, emailed to user, user fill it and email back to us.
3. from within PDF form, user need to load dynamic data from web (this is the challenge)
4. No access to folder level adobe javascript, so we can't use Adobe Javascript SOA nor Net.HTTP (CMIIW - SOA and Net.HTTP only available via folder level adobe javascript)

what I've done:

- A. use itext to inject adobeJavascript submitForm - done
- B. success submitting data to server - done
- C. my server side received and return data (I tried FDF format) - done
- D. from within the PDF file, I try to get the response data. I use this parameter called oJavaScript:After/oJavaScript:Before in submitForm method. I've played with the example, debug and no luck of getting any data. No called to "oJavaScript:After" function that I registered through submitForm. This is where I stuck.

So, with all the constraints, is it still possible? (either using oJavascript/other method). Any comment will be appreciated. Thanks.

Adobe javascript API reference
http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf

Comment: Do you have control over the dynamic data to be loaded by the user, or is that coming from an external source beyond your reach?

Comment: Yes I do have control over the dynamic data. I mean I will create the webservice/rest/json/or what so ever kind of data to be fed to the pdf files

Comment: Anyone could share any thoughts? thanks before