# Process submitted PDF file and FDF response

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to submit a pdf form to the mvc asp.net web application.

```
this.submitForm({
        cURL : this.getField('submitTo').value.toString(),  
        cSubmitAs :"FDF",
        oJavaScript : { Before : 'app.alert("Before")',  
                        After : 'app.alert("After")'}         
    });
```

This code handles the requests:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void SubmitPdf()
    {
        var fdfReader = new FdfReader(Request.InputStream);
        var fdfWriter = new FdfWriter();
        fdfWriter.SetFields(fdfReader);
        fdfReader.Close();

        fdfWriter.SetFieldAsString("TextArea", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());

        byte[] fdfbuffer;
        using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            fdfWriter.WriteTo(mstream);
            fdfbuffer = mstream.ToArray();
        }

        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.fdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;");
        var fdf = Encoding.Default.GetString(fdfbuffer);
        Response.Write(fdf);
    }
```

Everything works fine, the request gets processed and the FDF response goes back to the PDF Reader. 
In PDF Reader I can see updated value in the 'TextArea' textbox;

However by some reason I don't see alerts with 'Before' and 'After' messages.

I checked the value in the fdf variable before sending response to the client.
There is nothing related to After and Before scripts. I believe, it should have something like that (I have this text in the Request.InputStream):

```
2 0 obj << /After(app.alert\("After"\))/Before(app.alert\("Before"\))>> endobj
```

My question: how can I insert After and Before scripts to the FDF response using iTextSharp (v.5.5.4)?

I found similar question but it doesn't have the answer: 
[Loading external data from inside PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23729251/loading-external-data-from-inside-pdf-itext-and-adobe-javascript)
Thanks.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the object you use for passing the JavaScript code has to have the /JS key (either within, or in its reference); you might have a look at the description of FDF in the Portable Document Format Reference (aka ISO 32000).

Comment: If I don't use iTextSharp for updating some values in the SubmitPdf method and just send back the same FDF I get - everything works as expected. I can see alerts Before and After.